# Can non-encoded latin characters in this CSV be encoded into a new file?

Tags: python, csv, unicode, encoding, iso-8859-1

I have a csv file that was written in the following way (Python 2.7):

`with open(fileName, ‘w’) as csvOutput:  
    testData = csv.writer(csvOutput)
    testData.writerow([name.encode(‘utf-8’)])`

I was expecting the `utf-8` encoding to prevent characters like ’© from replacing what should be é in the resulting CSV.

When trying to convert the file to proper encoding, é, for instance, shows as \x92\xa9, and I can’t convert it:

`with open(“fileToConvert.csv”, "r") as f:`
      
    `rows = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter=","))`

```
   for row in rows:
       print row # this will print something like \x92\xa9, but will show as ’© in the file`
```

With the unicodecsv module as csv used below, I can write é to a CSV with the `latin-1` parameter, but it doesn’t work with this file, just with strings that are already encoded. A system that would handle any characters would be ideal, but figuring out this encoding issue is priority.

`with open('unicodeTest.csv', 'wb') as csvOutput:  

    testData = csv.writer(csvOutput, encoding='latin-1')
    testData.writerow(['é'])`

Comment: Could you edit to be more specific about what you think the problem is?  An encoding is a way of converting strings to bytes.  `b'\xc3\xa9'` is exactly what `"é"` encodes to in utf-8, and it'll only "show" as something like `'Ã©'` if you (or some program you call) _decodes_ that utf-8 using the wrong encoding scheme (such as latin-1).

Comment: `testData.writerow(['é'])` will show as é in the CSV file when using `latin-1`, so I'm trying to convert '\x92\xa9' (what is shown printed from the read csv in the python console) to 'é' (or some other encoding of it?) as it is still showing as ’© in the resulting file (whether using `latin-1` or not)

Comment: Again, "showing as [] in the resulting file" isn't a thing.  You're either looking at bytes, or you're looking at the results of a decoding.  I strongly recommend reading [this tutorial](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) on unicode, it's helped a lot of people.  And also plan to switch to Python 3. :-)

Comment: Yes, it is still *decoding to* ’© in the resulting file (whether using latin-1 or not). I'd rather get to a better version of me than Python, though (no morass).